# Reading the Visible Frame Buffer to a Pixel Buffer Object

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, gpu

I am try to capture screenshots and do some manipulations on them.
My goal is to use the CPU as little as possible and to take advantage of the GPU, so I would like to use CUDA to do the image manipulations.

As of now I am using the Windows API (StretchBlt and GetDIBits) to copy the framebuffer to the RAM and the use cudaMemcpy to copy it to VRAM.

These memory copies use the CPU and when copying many frames per seconds it gets really CPU intensive.
That is why I would like to copy the framebuffer directly to the VRAM for the use of CUDA.

I found a technique using OpenGL PBO as described here: http://gravisma.zcu.cz/GraVisMa-2010/Papers/Poster/F13-full.pdf and it sound like it might be the way to do it.

Are there examples of something of this sort?

Edit:

I also found this: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html.
It says:

> "The main advantage of PBO is fast pixel data transfer to and from a
>   graphics card through DMA (Direct Memory Access) without involing CPU
>   cycles. And, the other advantage of PBO is asynchronous DMA transfer."

So it does look like PBO is the right direction but again I am really unsure about how to do it.

Could you please exemplify with source code?

Platform: Windows XP (win32 only)

Comment: Are you trying to take a screenshot of the entire desktop or of an OpenGL application?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira, of the entire desktop.

Comment: I might be wrong, but you can't work with OpenGL PBO since Windows does not use OpenGL for rendering, so there is no information of what each pixel contains. You have to use what you are using and then import the bitmap data to the PBO.

Comment: On the links I provided they are saying it's possible. I am looking for a sample though for confirmation...

Comment: Two things: Reading the visible frame buffer (i.e. front buffer) into a PBO will work **only** if no DWM is active. Otherwise, you **must** use GDI. Also, as a nitpick, the main reason for using a PBO is not that a PBO transfers any faster, but asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to process the screenshots in CUDA, why not use the OpenGL interop? That lets you read the texture / buffer as an image. That way all the data stays on the GPU and CPU is never used.

Later, you can map the texture to CPU memory / pinned memory and save it to a file (since you want a screenshot). The transfer will happen as DMA and CPU is not involved either.